# How can C store a 1001 bit number in double data type?

Tags: c, double

This is the code to calculate 1000th power of 2.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double multiply = 1;
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
        multiply *= 2;
    }
    printf("%lf\n", multiply);
    return 0;
}
```

And the output on my system, as well as [ideone](http://ideone.com/JI2H0l)

```
10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703510511249361224931983788156958581275946729175531468251871452856923140435984577574698574803934567774824230985421074605062371141877954182153046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069376
```

which is exactly the right answer:

```
irb(main):001:0> 10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703510511249361224931983788156958581275946729175531468251871452856923140435984577574698574803934567774824230985421074605062371141877954182153046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069376 == 2 ** 1000
=> true
```

Comment: Note that `printf` `%lf` is wrong; it should be `%f`.

Comment: @melpomene `%lf` is correct for `double multiply`.

Comment: Maybe you can store your result in a string, and print it.

Comment: @melpomene: C 1999 7.19.6.1 7: “ **l** (ell) … has no effect on a following **a**, **A**, **e**, **E**, **f**, **F**, **g**, or **G** conversion specifier.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil True, `%lf` is equivalent to `%f` in C99, so it's not wrong there, just unnecessary. But in C89 printf `%lf` had undefined behavior, and some popular platforms still don't support C99 yet. So I think at least the "it should be `%f`" part is fully justified.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [IEEE 754](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), floats etc. are stored in a 2-power format: sign, mantissa and exponent for base 2.

So 2^1000 is, simply spoken, stored with a mantissa of exactly 1 and an exponent of 1000.

If you would add 2, the value isn't correct any longer.

Comment: Yes a `double` can store up to 52 binary digits of a number, but there can be up to 2^10 zeros in front or behind those digits.

Comment: @ams: The exponent range of normal 64-bit IEEE-754 binary floating-point numbers is -1022 to 1023. There is also an implicit leading 1 bit. So, if you want to convert a floating-point representation to binary, you may have 53 bits followed by up to 971 zeroes (not 2^10) or a period followed by up to 1021 (also not 2^10) zeroes followed by 53 bits, or a period in the middle of 53 bits.